# Bluetooth radio level

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android

Using monodroid I'm writing an android app featuring a bluetooth connection with a remote device. Is there a way to show to the user the strength of the bluetooth radio link between 2 device in comunication each other? I'd like something like the one avaible for wi-fi connection in the Os interface.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the signal strength at the time the device is discovered from the BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI during the ACTION_FOUND intent

There are no APIs to get the RSSI during a connection.